# Mediatek 7630E Bluetooth doesn't work

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, asus, mediatek

I'm new to Linux, just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer (Asus X552CL). The Wi-Fi didn't work at first, but I followed a tutorial from [here](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E). I got the Wi-Fi working, but the Bluetooth doesn't work. I tried to apply the patch on the tutorial, but at the end of the process, it tells me this:

```
./bpatch: line 164: cd: drivers/bluetooth/: No such file or directory
```

I found similar questions here, but they were not answered. I'm gonna include this info as well

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[    5.238248] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.238280] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.238284] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.238286] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.238293] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.493855] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[    5.534502] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.534504] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.534509] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

And this

```
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

How can I get Bluetooth to work? It is essential, because I use a bluetooth keyboard and headphones.

Comment: bluetooth keyboard? you don't have cold to your eyes, because it s not at all secured for a computer (we can see what you re doing all around 1 km with a good antenna). For the bluetooth, did you check the service with the following command `sudo service bluetooth status`

Comment: It says this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bYfZ9DwGK6/ It's not progressing any further. I closed the terminall after a while. ABout my bt keyboard, I really don't have any USB keyboards right now. I'm planning to get one though.

Comment: so the service is still running, sorry but I don't have any skills to help you more